# unable to show the balloon pop up when the input fields are not valid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to validate the email address fields(single email/multiple email addresses) using bootstrap/angularjs.
I have two input fields which takes single email address as input for the first field and single/multiple email addresses as input for the second input field.
Issue i'm facing is for the single email input field, it is validating the email address but when i terminated with `,`  or `;` it is showing the error. Even though it is single email address entry field if user accidently types `,` or `;` i want to accept it.Similarly with multiple Email field also when user type the valid email id and terminate with `,` or `;` it is not showing as valid email address.
Other issue is i want to show the balloon pop up with error message when user click on submit button if the user entered email address is not valid.

Demo which is not working : http://plnkr.co/edit/stBbGYrod6zDqA0vVIMD?p=preview

Working Demo : http://next.plnkr.co/edit/X6ONPdgLAZEcUXhy

In the above working demo, it is showing the error message if the email address is not valid which is correct but if terminated with `,` or `;` it is showing the error and the background of the input field is red.

sample html :

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head> 

  <body ng-app="myApp">
  <form name="shareSelectionForm"> 
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div>
      Single email:  <input type="email" class="form-control" required name="singleRecipientEmail" ng-model="singleRecipientEmail">
     <div ng-show="shareSelectionForm.$submitted || shareSelectionForm.singleRecipientEmail.$touched">
         <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="shareSelectionForm.singleRecipientEmail.$error.required">Email Address is not valid</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   <div>
     Single/Multiple email:  <input type="text" class="form-control" multiple-emails required name="recipientEmail" ng-model="recipientEmail">
   <div ng-show="shareSelectionForm.$submitted || shareSelectionForm.recipientEmail.$touched">
         <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="shareSelectionForm.recipientEmail.$error.required">Single/Multiple Email Address is not valid</p>
     </div>
      </div>

 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button>

    </div>  
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your custom directive code which checks with regex after splitting multiple emails by either `,` or `;`.

```
app.directive('multipleEmails', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        var emails = viewValue.split(/[ ,;]+/);
        var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
        var validityArr = emails.map(function(str) {
          if (str.trim()) {
            return re.test(str.trim());
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        });
        console.log(emails, validityArr);
        var atLeastOneInvalid = false;
        angular.forEach(validityArr, function(value) {
          if (value === false)
            atLeastOneInvalid = true;
        });
        if (!atLeastOneInvalid) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('multipleEmails', true);
          return viewValue;
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('multipleEmails', false);
          return undefined;
        }

      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here I've only updated `validityArr` to make it valid string even if it ends with `,` or `;`

[**Updated Working Example**](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/AURlsmDVBT25RMxT?preview)

Comment: The plunker you added is not working. Please find my updated plunker with your updated directive which is not working(not showing any error message on click of submit button : http://next.plnkr.co/edit/M3qPLqrVUxpNjfsO

Comment: @nan What you should do is disabled submit button untill form is valid. And on change of values just show the error messages. It'll be more handy for user. You can even use ng-model-options for that purpose. Here's updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/f66dYZnGaxn01txaMyLk?p=preview